# How to say the vertical vowel extension line in Japanese?

Tags: grammar, words, orthography

I'm learning katakana these days and my book introduces the horizontal line which is use to lengthen a vowel sound as in internet inta-netto

My book says this line is called yoko bou which I can find in the dictionary.

Then my book mentions that when writing in vertical script it is called tabe bou. I cannot find this in the dictionary. I speak Chinese so I already know about 横 horizontal and 纵 vertical. 纵 turns out to be tate in my dictionary.

So is tabe a typo/mistake or are tate and tabe both variants ? Or maybe tate changes to tabe when followed by bou ?

Comment: It must be a typo for たて. It is written as 縦 in Japanese kanji.

Answer (score 3):

*Bou* is just the reading for 棒【ぼう】 "bar; pole".  There are a few other names for this mark, as detailed in the JA Wikipedia article at [長音符](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%95%B7%E9%9F%B3%E7%AC%A6), and also some in the EN Wikipedia article at [Chōonpu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ch%C5%8Donpu):

- 長音符【ちょうおんぷ】 -- "long sound mark"
- 長音符号【ちょうおんふごう】 -- "long sound symbol"
- 長音記号【ちょうおんきごう】 -- "long sound notation"
- 音引き【おんびき】 -- "sound puller / lengthener"
- 棒引き【ぼうびき】 -- "bar puller / lengthener"
- 伸ばし【のばし】棒【ぼう】 -- "lengthener / stretcher bar"

As you noted, there are also:

- 横【よこ】棒【ぼう】 -- "horizontal bar / pole"
- 縦【たて】棒【ぼう】 -- "vertical bar / pole"